# Unusual JSON format (equal signs for key value pairs) and parsing it

Tags: c#, json, pusher

After updating the pusher.com libraries for one of my VS WinForms projects, I've noticed that the JSON I'm receiving from pusher.com is not in the correct format anymore (nothing was changed on the server end of things, just the library update in the desktop app / VS project).

Instead of getting this (after the desktop application I'm making receives it, and displays it via `MessageBox.Show(...)`):

```
{
    "event": "myevent",
    "data": {
        "message": {
            "header": {
                "type": "type1",
                "printer": "myprinter"
            },
            "items": {
                "1": "Item 1@03@Kg@1@1782.00@1782.00@6002@03"
            },
            "info": {
                "type": "stuff",
                "other": "yes"
            }
        }
    },
    "channel": "mychannel"
}
```

I am now getting this

```
{
    event = cashregister,
    data = {
        "message": {
            "header": {
                "type":"type1",
                "printer":"myprinter"
            },
            "items": {
                "1":"Item 1@03@Kg@1@1782.00@1782.00@6002@03"
            },
            "info": {
                "type":"stuff",
                "other":"yes"
            }
        }
    },
    channel = mychannel,
    user_id =  
}
```

I've never seen this kind of JSON formatting before, and have not been able to find anything by searching on Google or visiting json.org and going through examples.

The usual `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJson.event.ToString());` is not working, and it's throwing an exception - `Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: =.`

How do I parse this? More importantly, is this even a proper JSON format?

Comment: As far as I know that second box is not valid JSON

Comment: It's definitely not valid JSON. I would see if you can use Fiddler or something similar to see whether the response on the network is correct.